# Se puede guardar varios elementos en una variable e javascript

Tags: javascript

Quiero saber si a una variable le puedo asignar lo de varios elementos por ejemplo:

```
var nombreVariable = $("elemento1","elemento2","elemento3").val();
```

Comment: ¿qué almacenan elemento 1, 2 y 3? son etiquetas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Las variables en JS almacenan un valor el cual es asignado a ella de esta forma:

```
let variable = valor;
```

El cual puede tener inicialmente alguno de los tipos de datos primitivos:

- **`string`**
- **`number`**
- **`boolean`**
- **`undefined`**
- **`null`**
- **`bigint`**
- **`symbol`**

Sin embargo para casos como este tenemos tipos o estructuras de datos un tanto mas complejas que nos ayudarían a lograr dicho objetivo, por ejemplo:

**Los objetos**

Los cuales son un arreglo de clave: valor similar a esto:

```
let valores = {
   clave1: valor1,
   clave2: valor2,
   .........
}
```

Para tu caso específico entonces debería ser así:

```
let elemento1 = document.getElementById("elemento1")
let elemento2 = document.getElementById("elemento2")
let elemento3 = document.getElementById("elemento3")

let valores = {
    variable1: elemento1.value, 
    variable2: elemento2.value,
    variable3: elemento3.value
}
```

**SEGUNDA OPCIÓN**

Mediante un *vector* pues debemos tener presente que:

- JS nos permite almacenar valores de distinto tipo en el mismo vector

Quedando así:

```
let valores = [elemento1.value, elemento2.value, elemento3.value]
```